# updateOnContentResize: true not updating the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mcustomscrollbar

Please see in fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NifrasBcs/cwjfuzee/142/

```
var message =new Vue({
  el: '#message',
  data: {
    messages:{},
    message:'',
  },
  created: function() {
    this.getMessages();
  },
});
```

While clicks on "LOAD OLDER MESSAGES", The scroll bar not getting update.
Even when i call explicitly `$('#scroller').mCustomScrollbar('update')` on console, it's not getting update.

Can anyone fix it?

Advanced Thanks

Comment: I am seeing it is executing the callback: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/cwjfuzee/143/

Comment: Yes I also have noticed that, Why then it's not getting update the scroll bar?

Comment: Even i explicitly  called $('#scroller').mCustomScrollbar('update').